# Resource not found when using terraformer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraformer

I am running this command

```
terraformer import aws --resources=lambda --regions=us-east-1
```

and getting the following error:

> 2022/12/28 12:35:19 aws error initializing resources in service lambda, err: operation error Lambda: GetPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 404, RequestID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx, ResourceNotFoundException: The resource you requested does not exist.

can someone assist?

I have checked that i can pull the lambdas using aws cli and i am getting them properly

Comment: I and others have same problem : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/issues/1599

Answer (score 0):

It's an open issue, probably related to
failing on finding the first lambda with no resource policy (inline policy doesn't cut it apparently). so, if you can put a resource policy on all your lambdas you should get it to work.

See the thread here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/issues/1599